# NOOBQ: How to pass HTML input argument to .py as query term?

Tags: python, html

This is the first time I'm going outside of HTML/CSS or python.

I have a simple HTML page with a text input. I'd like to pass this to python and use it as a search term.  I have the .py script working already (i.e. it takes a search term and produces results).

I have been reading about cgi-bin but have no earthly idea what to do next.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured cgi-scripting on your server?

Comment: If you have, then all you need to do is make an ajax call to that .py file. Refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), for more info on ajax.

Comment: I don't have cgi-scripting configured. I'll search around for how to do that; thanks for this (and any additional info much appreciated).